# MySQL/VB.NET - An address incompatible with the requested protocol was used

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I have a trivial VB script which I am using to connect to a MySQL database on a Windows Server (2012 R2).

It's all super simple, out of the box "connect to MySql example" stuff.

I have verified that MySQL is listening on all local IPV4 addresses. I can connect with MySQL workbench with the same parameters. Yet I get a weird error when connecting via my program:

```
An address incompatible with the requested protocol was used
```

My connect string is as follows:

"server=127.0.0.1;database=test;uid=xx;pwd=xx"

It appears the connection tries to use IPV6 when connecting. How is this possible?

I suspect some kind of firewall is modifying or blocking my network connection, but it is a "new" machine for me and I don't know what's installed.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I just did a test with a newer version of MySQL.Data.dll (the connector library), and it did connect! There must be a compatibility version between the MySQL I have and the connector version the app is compiled with.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was due to an old MySQL Connector DLL (MySQL.Data.dll) version which was either incompatible with Windows (hence the networking error message) or the version of MySQL I'm running. After upgrading the dll, the connection worked properly.

This may help out someone who has a similar problem, as the error is highly misleading.